# Is it possible to manage group of vms in openstack as a single instance?

Tags: virtual-machines, openstack, openstack-nova

I am reviewing openstack technology as a possible solution for creating sandboxes. What I am going to do is to create instances that contains several vms connected within virtual network. There will be several instances per one host.

I researched commandline nova management tool and as I understand it does not provide with management of several VMs as a single group.

To explain in more details I need something like:

```
nova boot [instance-name] --image <image_of_several_vms>
```

So my question: Is that possible to manage several vms as a single group by commandline or ui tools?

Comment: I mean, the point would be for you to use the API via an SDK, the python client methods, or directly to do that from your own code or orchestration tool.  That's pretty out of scope for what OpenStack is doing.  It does certainly provide you the API utilities to do it yourself though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt, will think about another solution

Comment: you might check out mesos from apache foundation.

Comment: Isn't this what the "Stacks" function of OpenStack does? Haven't tried it myself, but I know other teams here use it to describe their systems as a whole.